# I cannot figure out the difference between two simple codes

Tags: c#

I was trying to write a simple code in C# and my compiler, Visual Studio, suggested a different version of my code that I couldn't understand the difference.

This is what I had first:

```cs
        public void addCard(Card card)
        {
            foreach (Card inDeckCard in cardDeck)
            {
                if (card.name == inDeckCard.name)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            cardDeck.Add(card);
        }
```

and this is what the compiler suggested:

```cs
        public void addCard(Card card)
        {
            foreach (Card inDeckCard in cardDeck)
            {
                if (card.name == inDeckCard.name)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            cardDeck.Add(item: card);
        }
```

What is the difference between when I have `item:` and when I don't. What actually does `item:` mean/do in this case?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's using Named Arguments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

Excerpt:

> PrintOrderDetails("Gift Shop", 31, "Red Mug");*
>
> If you do not remember the order of the parameters but know their names, you can send the arguments in any order.*
>
> PrintOrderDetails(orderNum: 31, productName: "Red Mug", sellerName: "Gift Shop");*
>
> PrintOrderDetails(productName: "Red Mug", sellerName: "Gift Shop", orderNum: 31);*

Not sure what type CardDeck is and what the calling signature of the Add method is, but `item: card` says that the card argument is to be matched with the item parameter.

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot to add, cardDeck is a card List, List<Card>, where I have another class for cards and a class for the deck of cards. I just didn't understand what `item:` stands for. So, in that case, is `item:` really necessary to use?

Comment: No, not really. Named Arguments are required if you're providing multiple arguments in a different order than they are declared. With a method that takes a single argument, it's unnecessary. The Visual Studio "recommendation" may have just been a "click here to do this optional action" [depending on the icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions?view=vs-2019#icons).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, there is ***no*** difference at all.

Syntactically, VS is suggesting an alternative that may provide more information to the developer.

Named arguments allow you to, in your calling code, address both optional and non-optional arguments, though most uses of named arguments at the call site address optional arguments and in a way that doesn't require ordering of the arguments.

In fact, tools like ReSharper, will suggest that addressing by name for non-optional arguments is redundant. That said, it can be useful to address non-optional arguments by name when the API you are using falls outside of good API design. For example a "bad" method `ValidateStuff()` taking in a `boolean` parameter, for example, `shouldCheckCreditCardScore`, when read by a developer at the call site doesn't provide much value.

```
ValidateStuff(false) vs. ValidateStuff(true)
```

doesn't really tell you anything. But

```
ValidateStuff(shouldCheckCreditCardScore: false) vs. ValidateStuff(shouldCheckCreditCardScore: true)
```

provides much more information. Your example, semantically, does the same thing in each case. I would argue that `item` is not a useful reason to name the argument at the call site though; my example above, where the name of the argument is specified at the call site, provides useful information.

Comment: so in my case instead of `item:` I can do `Card:` since I am working with cards and and a deck of cards etc.